# Symfony3 File upload path not working in production

Tags: php, nginx, file-upload, symfony-3.1

I am making a small portfolio website with symfony. Everything works on my local machine, I can upload portfolio items, etc etc.

On my droplet however (Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64, running Nginx)

So I follow the guide for uploading files at http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

Everything works locally, but I get a 500 error on my production droplet.
I checked my logs for the error, and it seems that, the path I set up in my parameters :

(`portfolio_directory: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/portfolio'`)

gives the following error

`[2016-09-20 12:36:33] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException: "Unable to write in the "/var/www/wsly/www/app/../web/images/portfolio" directory" at /var/www/wsly/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.php line 113 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\File\\Exception\\FileException(code: 0): Unable to write in the \"/var/www/wsly/www/app/../web/images/portfolio\" directory at /var/www/wsly/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.php:113)"}`

Now the permissions for the entire images folder is set to 777 (I used chmod -R 777 for this) so I don't think the issue is actually that the permission, but rather that the path is incorrect? Not sure but app/../web is not a valid path, it seems to literally copy the path as the root directory is the app directory? instead of up one level with the /../

Can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: `/var/www/wsly/www/app/../web/images/portfolio` sounds completely valid to me. What happens when you login via the terminal and type `ls -l /var/www/wsly/www/app/../web/images/portfolio`?

Comment: Does you web-server run as a different user to the Symfony installation? If so, the web user needs access along the entire filepath!

Comment: @BenHillier I get a list of all the images in the folder (there are still some in there from  from dev, since I use git to maintain it and apparently forgot to add it to the gitignore).

Everything runs on the root user, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I somehow doubt that your webserver daemon is running as root. That would be a big security risk, and any default setup would set it up that way. I'm more of an Apache than an Nginx user, so I can't offer you much insight on how to check that.

Comment: @BenHillier is it possible the folder should be owned by www-data instead of the root user?

Comment: @BenHillier thanks for the insight, that seemed to be the issue. I just realized my dev environment is apache and not nginx and the root user is a differnent user than the www-data. I'm really new to servers and such, so thanks a bunch for that!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and spent many days experimenting
I eventually fixed it by using this format for the destination

```
upload_destination: ../web/images/profiles
```